# compare two sheets in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

want to compare two sheets in same workbook and highlight each cell which differ in both sheets. took This as reference [fastest way to Compare two sheets in same workbook in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70054851/fastest-way-to-compare-two-sheets-in-same-workbook-in-excel) . Approach is put sheet to object to dictionary to object to sheet. Currently modified it to and was able to compare where struck with error '438' object doesn't support this property or method at  ## If sMetric = dict(sKey) Then ## block

Can take any values to compare in both sheets but try to take few different values to do see the comparison. i want cell by cell compare and highlight those cells only which are different. This is done at that if sMetric = dict(sKey) block mean while just adding a space next to value so that i can do a conditional formatting such that color red cells which contain space like that.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand what you wrote and assume that your code is more complicated than necessary. Also, I find it irritating that you store the two worksheet references in an array, but okay, that's how you do it.  `ws(2)(2,4)` is invalid (`sheet1(2,4)` would also be invalid). Do you mean `ws(2).Cells(2,4)` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use conditional formatting for this?

Comment: This approach is just to make comparison faster as cell by cell is very much slower for very large data set. So did a object to dictionary approach and back forth.

Comment: No specific reason not to use but just focused on speed. Need to do it using vba

Comment: are the "key" column value combinations unique for a given worksheet, or can the same combination occur more than once?

Comment: If you want speed and need to use via VBA then apply conditional formatting using VBA? Excel built-in functionality usually work faster.

Comment: @Arun, please, once you get it working, try simple conditional formatting too and please report which is faster. When I did this, I had a specific cell on each sheet that held the name of the prior table being compared to, a hidden column in the table that used MATCH to find the corresponding row number (sidestepping sorting, extra rows, missing rows, etc), then my conditional formatting compared the cell value vs `INDEX(INDIRECT($B$3 & "[" & A$5 & "]"), $Z6)` were B3 is the prior table's name, the current table's first column title is A5, and Z was the hidden row number column.

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem to me, I took a stab at a perhaps more generalized problem which may not exactly match your requirements but thought I'd share the approach.

In this approach, I'm creating two identically sized array for two `Range` objects. If the objects occupy the same relevant areas in both sheets you should be able to do the comparison with arrays only. Dictionaries tend to slow down as a lot of items get added, so I think this solution has a potential to be faster. A quick test on my machine executes the below code in ~0.5 seconds.

The code really only works if you have data starting in A1 and going down, although it should be possible to calculate the offsets needed to make this more generalized.

Have a look, hope it helps.

```
Option Explicit

'Run this sub
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim t As Single: t = timer
    Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C500000")
    Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:C500000")
    CompareRanges rng1, rng2
    Debug.Print timer - t & " seconds"
End Sub

Private Sub CompareRanges(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    Dim Rows    As Long
    Dim Columns As Long
    
    Rows = IIf(rng1.Rows.Count > rng2.Rows.Count, rng1.Rows.Count, rng2.Rows.Count)
    Columns = IIf(rng1.Columns.Count > rng2.Columns.Count, rng1.Columns.Count, rng2.Columns.Count)
    
    Dim Rng1Array As Variant: Rng1Array = SheetToArray(rng1.Parent, Rows, Columns)
    Dim Rng2Array As Variant: Rng2Array = SheetToArray(rng2.Parent, Rows, Columns)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim rng1Sheet As Worksheet: Set rng1Sheet = rng1.Parent
    Dim rng2Sheet As Worksheet: Set rng2Sheet = rng2.Parent
    
    Dim ConditionalFormatRng1 As Range
    Dim ConditionalFormatRng2 As Range
    
    For i = LBound(Rng1Array, 2) To UBound(Rng1Array, 2)
        
        For j = LBound(Rng1Array, 1) To UBound(Rng1Array, 1)
            
            If Rng1Array(j, i) <> Rng2Array(j, i) Then
                
                If ConditionalFormatRng1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set ConditionalFormatRng1 = rng1Sheet.Cells(j, i)
                    Set ConditionalFormatRng2 = rng2Sheet.Cells(j, i)
                Else
                    Set ConditionalFormatRng1 = Union(rng1Sheet.Cells(j, i), ConditionalFormatRng1)
                    Set ConditionalFormatRng2 = Union(rng2Sheet.Cells(j, i), ConditionalFormatRng2)
                End If
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
    Next
   
    ConditionalFormatRng1.Interior.Color = vbRed
    ConditionalFormatRng2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    
End Sub

Private Function SheetToArray(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                              Rows As Long, _
                              Columns As Long) As Variant
                              
    With Sheet
       SheetToArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows, Columns)).Value2
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Ryan. thanks for your help. Can you post same approach using dictionaries if possible.

Comment: Hi Arun, my point in the code above is you should be able to achieve the same (or possibly faster performance), without using dictionaries. Array access for an element is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this. Two options.

```
Sub checkrev()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Sh1LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh1Range = .Range("A1:A" & Sh1LastRow)
End With
With Sheets("Sheet2")
Sh2LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh2Range = .Range("A1:A" & Sh2LastRow)
End With

'compare sheet 1 with sheet 2
For Each Sh1cell In Sh1Range
Set c = Sh2Range.Find( _
what:=Sh1cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
Sh1cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
If Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1) <> c.Offset(0, 1) Then
Sh1cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
End If
Next Sh1cell
'compare sheet 2 with sheet 1
For Each Sh2cell In Sh2Range
Set c = Sh1Range.Find( _
what:=Sh2cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
Sh2cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
If Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1) <> c.Offset(0, 1) Then
Sh2cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
End If
Next Sh2cell

End Sub


Sub CheckRev_v2()
'====================
'Originating author: Joel from "microsoft.public.excel.programming" 10.09.07
'====================
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Sh1LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh1Range = .Range("A1:A" & Sh1LastRow)
End With
With Sheets("Sheet2")
Sh2LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sh2Range = .Range("A1:A" & Sh2LastRow)
End With

'compare sheet 1 with sheet 2
For Each Sh1cell In Sh1Range
Set c = Sh2Range.Find( _
what:=Sh1cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "No Match Found!"
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Color = -16776961
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Bold = True
'Sh1cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'enters Revlevel
Else
If Sh1cell.Offset(0, 1) <> c.Offset(0, 1) Then
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Italic = True
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 2).ColumnWidth = 25
Sh1cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Revision Level Change!"
End If
End If
Next Sh1cell
'compare sheet 2 with sheet 1
For Each Sh2cell In Sh2Range
Set c = Sh1Range.Find( _
what:=Sh2cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "No Match Found!"
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Color = -16776961
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Bold = True
'Sh2cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'enters Revlevel
Else
If Sh2cell.Offset(0, 1) <> c.Offset(0, 1) Then
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Italic = True
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 2).ColumnWidth = 25
Sh2cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Revision Level Change!"
End If
End If
Next Sh2cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

[image]

After:

[image]